# Data too long for column 'mycolumn' at row 1 in RODBC

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I am using `sqlSave` function from `RODBC` package to save an R dataframe to a MySQL table:

```
sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "table", append = TRUE, rownames = "id", addPK = TRUE, fast = FALSE)
```

but it returns an error:

```
Data too long for column 'mycolumn' at row 1
```

I know what the error means (column has `nchar` greater than 255), but don't know how to fix it. I suppose I should use another char type but `sqlSave` function allows only 4 types: integer, varchar(255), varchar(5) and float.

Comment: " I suppose I should use another char type but sqlSave function allows only 4 types: integer, varchar(255), varchar(5) and float." Looks like you can add "Custom" datatype "varTypes
    an optional named character vector giving the DBMSs datatypes to be used for some (or all) of the columns if a table is to be created"  source https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/topics/sqlSave

Comment: I don't understand how to use it. I give it typs, but it returns an error: argument `'varTypes' has no names and will be ignored`

Comment: "I don't understand how to use it" i believe you need to can use the function `sqlColumns(...)` in combination with `sqlSave(... varType...)` something like `columns <- sqlColumns(connection, databaseName) varTypes <- as.character(columns$TYPE_NAME) names(varTypes) <- as.character(columns$COLUMN_NAME)  sqlSave(.....
varTypes=varTypes)`

Comment: Still can't get it. Can You shoe example if there are 3 columns, one varchar(255) and one with number of characters bigger than that (bigger than 255).